# Serilog fails to log c:\program files directory

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am using serilog and the output path to write is the c:\program files directory.
When serilog logs a message the log file never appears in the c:\program files directory.
I even tried setting the path to a subdirectory in the c:\program files directory. Serilog still failed to log to the subdirectory?

This just seems to stupid.
Can Serilog create a the log file and log message to the c:\program files directory or a subdirectory?

Comment: Note that programs need certain permissions to write to the Windows "C:\Program Files" directory, or any of its sub-directories. It's likely that you don't have this. For more information, a [site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=permissions+program+files+directory) lists several pertinent questions about this, e.g., [Request permission to write to Program Files directory during run time](/q/4417896) and [IO within the Program Files Directory](/q/5838025).

Comment: But don't do that - log files simply dont mix with `Program files` for a reason. This is why `ProgramData` exists. Go look up `APPDATA` and general log storage information, because this is not really a programming question, and putting logs in program files is just a simple no.

Comment: As usual just comments and talking points from people who probably googled for something post.  More are less just worthless comments who know way to solve the problem ask I know it takes persons on those directories, and for the dope who said do not that, IT HAS TO BE DONE LIKE that according to the client. Sorry I even posted this question.